# How to handle multiple event listener in react js?

Tags: reactjs

```
 dragElement.on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {

    dragElement.addClass('draggable');
    resizeElement.addClass('resizable');

    // Check if it's a mouse or touch event and pass along the correct value
    var startX = (e.pageX) ? e.pageX : e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

    // Get the initial position
    var dragWidth = dragElement.outerWidth(),
        posX = dragElement.offset().left + dragWidth - startX,
        containerOffset = container.offset().left,
        containerWidth = container.outerWidth();

    // Set limits
    minLeft = containerOffset + 10;
    maxLeft = containerOffset + containerWidth - dragWidth - 10;

    // Calculate the dragging distance on mousemove.
    dragElement.parents().on("mousemove touchmove", function(e) {

      // Check if it's a mouse or touch event and pass along the correct value
      var moveX = (e.pageX) ? e.pageX : e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

      leftValue = moveX + posX - dragWidth;

      // Prevent going off limits
      if ( leftValue < minLeft) {
        leftValue = minLeft;
      } else if (leftValue > maxLeft) {
        leftValue = maxLeft;
      }

      // Translate the handle's left value to masked divs width.
      widthValue = (leftValue + dragWidth/2 - containerOffset)*100/containerWidth+'%';

      // Set the new values for the slider and the handle. 
      // Bind mouseup events to stop dragging.
      $('.draggable').css('left', widthValue).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('draggable');
        resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
      });
      $('.resizable').css('width', widthValue);
    }).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel', function(){
      dragElement.removeClass('draggable');
      resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  }).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel', function(e){
    dragElement.removeClass('draggable');
    resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
  });
```

Hi , I am beginner in reactJs. I need to convert above JS Code in reactJS. Basically i have to create div comparison slider like image comparison slider. at above code i got stuck.  Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some react code and where did you have got stuck?
In general, you can add event listeners to the element inside the render method, or  you can add a ref to your elements in the render method and in the onComponentDidMount do some work on the element.

Comment: public componentDidMount() {
            this.drags(ragElement, resizeElement, container)
          }
         
          private drags(dragElement: any, resizeElement: any, container: any) {
            const e = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.audio);
            if (e) {
              e.addEventListener("mousedown touchstart", () => {
            });
            }
          }
          private handleResize() {
            const width = this.container.offsetWidth + "px";
            this.resizeElement.style.width = width;
          }
        }

Comment: Basically i am confused. how to call event listener in chain. As u have seen in JS code, event listener is calling in chain.

Comment: addEventListener is not chainable  because it doesn't return an object.
You need to call addEventListener twice.